# How to access mix() path from javascript

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-mix

I have compiled my assets with Laravel mix. In blade file, the traditional way is

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">`

Favicon also works:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ mix('/favicon/favicon-16x16.png') }}">`

What am I trying to do is, utilising `mix()` helper inside javascript, so that in my javascript I can access the cached asset path.

So in my component, I can do:

```
<img :src="mix_path('/img/hello.svg')" />
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

What comes to my mind is creating a global mixin and use that method in my read my mix-manifest.json and put the version id.

---

**Edit:** Use `window` object answer. That's sounds fine (as a workaround) as long as you don't use SSR as window object is not defined.

Maybe is there a way to write a javascript helper method to access the manifest.json to get the versioned path? Is it possible?

---

**Update:** This is how I solved it:

[How to read mix-manifest.json from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583374/how-to-read-mix-manifest-json-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To pass PHP variables to the javascript will require you echo them to the page when it is loaded within a PHP file (i.e. a `Blade` template).

If you want to use them in pure javascript files, you could do something as simple as assigning them to properties of the `window` object

Comment: Hmm, passing all the images paths to a `window` object? Like `window.imagePaths = [mix('/path'), ...]`? That'd work but seems like a very messy road, also you won't be able to use `window` object with SSR

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing it with every image! Just for the paths to things like the css & js files. If you make the paths to your images relative, then you can just store an asset path (`window.assetPath`) and then prepend it where necessary