# How to read mix-manifest.json from javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I cached my images using laravel-mix. For the image in blade, it works. However I couldn't figure out how to access that versioned paths from javascript.

Is it possible to read `mix-manifest.json` from compiled javascript? So that I can create a mixin and get the versioned paths

For example, in my mix-manifest.json I have

`"/images/hello.svg": "/images/hello.svg?id=0360de485c68385550da",`

and I thought if I can read the `mix-manifest.json` from my compiled javascript, I can create a helper method like

```
export default {
  methods: {
     mixPath(path) {
        let manifestObj = // read mix-manifest.json
        return manifestObj[path];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The mix manifest is in the public directory so `<your server hostname>/mix-manifest.json` should be enough to access it. You can can probably read this via AJAX however this means your functions that use it will all be async

Comment: I'm using SSR, so client can access `axios.get('/mix-manifest.json')` as you said but not the server :/ Any idea how to do that with server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could access mix-manifest.json with

```
const vm = this;

if (!Vue.prototype.BROWSER_BUILD) {
     let path = require("path");
     this.manifestPaths = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(path.resolve('./mix-manifest.json'), 'utf8'));
} else {
     axios.get('/mix-manifest.json').then(json => {
        vm.manifestPaths = json.data
     })
}
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
    mix(path) {
        if (typeof this.manifestPaths[path] == 'undefined') {
            return this.manifestPaths[path];
        }

        return path;
    }
}
```

---

*If you know a better way, i'd be happy to know :)*